# Applying a function to contained objects, provided they derive from a base type

Tags: c++

I'm having a hard time synthesizing my problem and I'm not sure the title summarizes it very well :/

I'm trying to keep an map of polymorphic containers in a structure in order to have a nice flat array of objects.

My trouble is that I want to apply a function on the objects contained, but only those derived from a specified Base type. Down there is a stripped down version of what I am trying to achieve.

```
struct BaseStock {};

template <typename ContainedType>
struct Stock : BaseStock {
    std::vector<ContainedType> container;
};

struct Store {
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<BaseStock>> stocks;

    template <typename Base>
    void something() {
        for (auto& pair: stocks) {
            // Here, do somehting only if pair.second's
            // contained type derives from Base
        }
    }
};
```

I tried to access contained elements from `BaseStock` by returning `void*` but it's impossible to `dynamic_cast` from it, thus disallowing a type check. The `stocks` map keeps the `type_index` of the Stock's contained type   but it's impossible to retrieve hierarchy information from that either.

Allowing the `BaseStock` to return something that could be checked against seemed to be the closest solution, but it would mean to force the `ContainedType` to always derive from something (which is not bad at all, but I like the idea of a container that doesn't imposes restrictions on the types you're using)

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want, feel free to request a larger explanation on something you don't get in the comments.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <typeindex>
#include <memory>

struct BaseStock {};
template <typename ContainedType>
struct Stock : BaseStock {
    std::vector<ContainedType> container;
};

struct Store {
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<BaseStock>> stocks;
    template <typename Base>
    void something() {
        for (auto& pair: stocks) {
            if (typeid(pair.first) != typeid(Base)) {
                std::cout << "Checking via typeid.\n";
            }
        }
    }
};

template<typename BaseType, typename DerivedType = BaseType> 
void InsertIntoStore(Store* store) {
    store->stocks[typeid(BaseType)] =
        std::unique_ptr<BaseType>(std::make_unique<DerivedType>());
} 

int main() {
    Store store;
    // Put two things into the map.
    InsertIntoStore<BaseStock, Stock<int>>(&store);
    InsertIntoStore<BaseStock>(&store);      
    // But only get one output.
    store.something<BaseStock>();
}
```

Comment: In your implementation there can still be only one BaseStock per type_index ! Putting a vector of BaseStock solves that.
But your answer is correct and interesting anyway :)

Comment: You want an `unordered_multimap`, which you did not elude to in your question. Please accept my answer if it adequately answers the question you posted.

Comment: Yeah well I was waiting for some other answers that would cover other aspects, but yours indeed "adequately answers the question" I posted